# align 3 buttons which are in 3 different div aligned

Tags: html, button, alignment

Here's what I have : [3 buttons in 3 diff div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igNUc.png)

What I want is to align these buttons which are in 3 different parent container as you can see in my screenshot. The third button is already at the very bottom of its div. The first and the second button are not, they should be at the exact same position of the third button in their div. How to do that ?

EDIT : the html template (angular) :

```
<div style="flex: 1;">
      <ng-container *ngIf="data.dialogData.currentP == undefined || !areSamePlans(data.dialogData.currentP.plan, product.plan); else currentPlan">
        <button style="color: white; background-color: purple; font-weight: bold; bottom: 0;"
        mat-raised-button (click)="chooseProduct(product)">CHOOSE PLAN</button>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #currentPlan><button mat-button disabled style="color: purple; font-weight: bold;">CURRENT PLAN</button></ng-template>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to give stylesheet in button :
 style="position:absolute; bottom:0px"

so your button placed to bottom in all 3 div.

Comment: the third button messed up : https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/01/ou1p.png